# How to go back on a particular fragment from other fragments by back button click in navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android

I know this topic discussed here previously, but none of them are fruitful for my code. What I did:

**in Home.java (navigation drawer main activity)** used this for navigation drawer function

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_breakfast) {
        fragmentClass = Breakfast.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_lunch) {
        fragmentClass = Lunch.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_wallet) {
        fragmentClass = Wallet.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {
        fragmentClass = History.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_reset) {
        fragmentClass = ResetPass.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        fragmentClass = ContactUs.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
        fragmentClass = Help.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        fragmentClass = AboutUs.class;
    }

    try {
        assert fragmentClass != null;
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    assert drawer != null;
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

Each and every declared fragments open by clicking on navigation drawer item selection. In other hand I also create another fragment which is set to open by default when the Home activity actually start

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        fragmentClass = AllProduct.class;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

and on onBackPressed() I used this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else {
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

and the all fragment activities coded like this manner:

```
public class AllProduct extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_product, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}
```

}

Now everything work fine, just one single problem. Suppose I want to open Fragment [1] from navigation drawer (not the above mentioned default fragment), then again open navigation drawer and open Fragment [2], then Fragment [3]. Now suppose I am in Fragment [3] and by pressing on back button I directly want to go the above mentioned Default fragment. It first going to Fragment [2], fragment [1] then default fragment. But I want where ever, in which fragment I am, i must go back to default fragment by back button press.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(...)
    .addToBackStack("tag").commit()
```

And remove all other code especially the one in onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally solve this problem, just remove .addToBackStack(null) from onNavigationItemSelected. Then add:

```
 getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                Fragment fragment = null;
                Class fragmentClass;
                fragmentClass = AllProduct.class;
                try {
                    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

in every fragment under onResume()

and delete:

```
else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```